# Lookup total based on a lookup table SUMIF

Tags: excel, sum, excel-2010, conditional-statements, array-formulas

I need to do a total sum based on a look up, however the look up is dynamic. To be more specific I have a totals table like so:

```
Type    | Total
Charges | 633.86
Costs   |
Misc    |
```

This needs to sum up figures based on certain code in a look up table:

```
Type    | Code
Charges | N77RE
Charges | N5762
Charges | M7YRE
Costs   | M888
Costs   | O999
MISC    | ABCS12
MISC    | ABCs13
MISC    | ABCS14
```

The financial data is presented like so:

```
Transaction | Code  | Costs
123456      | N77RE | 19.99
123454      | O999  | 24.99
123452      | N5762 | 458.99
123450      | O999  | 487.55
123448      | N5762 | 45.55
```

So to sum it up I need to do a look up function to check to see what code has what value and then sum it up?

This image is based on the answer, it only seems to sum up the first `Code`?

[image]

Comment: sorry it only pasted in a bit of the financial data!

Comment: as the answer below it would be 524.53 as it would sum up all the fields that match that code.

Comment: it only seems to calculate whats in the first cell? Barrys answer is really close just not quiet right!

Comment: then i must have missed something obvious? But cant see what?

Comment: updated the image to show arrays

Comment: got it. sorry excel isnt my main app. thanks for clearing it up.

Comment: @pnuts +1 for "barry's answers are always correct" - I wish that were true!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your second table (Types and Codes) is in `D1:E9` and the third table (Transactions, Codes and Costs) is in `G1:I6` then with `"Charges"` in `A2` use this "array formula" in B2

`=SUM(SUMIF(H$2:H$6,IF(D$2:D$9=A2,E$2:E$9),I$2:I$6))`

confirm with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

and copy down as required

The `IF` function provides a list of the valid codes for the type in A2 then `SUMIF` sums the costs for each code. This gives you an array of totals which `SUM` then sums to give your final answer.

For the example shown I'd expect to get `524.53` as the total for Charges

Comment: Replicated the above however only the charges is populating and only for 19.99 (the top code?? - added picture above –

Comment: Sorry, I've been away from my PC, is it all working now?